# Take three images with camera and insert into three diffefent imageViews

Tags: android, image, camera

I need to upload 3 different images into different image view. I've tried the code snippet given below. any help would be appreciated. I trying to take and image and set over the `ImageView`
here is my java file

```java
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.OutputStream;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        ImageView viewImage;
        ImageView viewImage1;
        ImageView viewImage2;
        Button b;
        EditText firm_name;
        EditText owner_name;
        EditText adress;
        EditText mob_num;
        EditText email;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            firm_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firm_name);
            owner_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.owner_name);
            adress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.adress);
            mob_num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mob_num);
            email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
            viewImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
            viewImage1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
            viewImage2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv2);
            viewImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    selectImage();
                }
            });
            viewImage1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    selectImage();
                }
            });
            viewImage2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    selectImage();
                }
            });

        }


        private void selectImage() {
            final CharSequence[] options = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery", "Cancel"};
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
            builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    if (options[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                    } else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
                    } else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        if (requestCode == 1) {
                            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
                            for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                                if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                                    f = temp;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            try {
                                Bitmap bitmap;
                                BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                                        bitmapOptions);
                                viewImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                                viewImage1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                                viewImage2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                                String path = android.os.Environment
                                        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                        + File.separator
                                        + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                                f.delete();
                                OutputStream outFile = null;
                                File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                                try {
                                    outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                                    outFile.flush();
                                    outFile.close();
                                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } else if (requestCode == 2) {
                            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                            String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
                            c.moveToFirst();
                            int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
                            String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
                            c.close();
                            Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                            viewImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                            viewImage1.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                            viewImage2.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

                        }


                    }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to explain first what do you use to capture the images? 
Let's say you want to use this library: https://github.com/JagarYousef/DialogCameraView 
You can add onClickListener() for per of your image views to display the camera dialog:

```
CameraViewDialog cameraViewDialog = new CameraViewDialog();
cameraViewDialog.init(context, image_path);
cameraViewDialog.setOnCaptureDoneListener(new OnCaptureDone() {
    @Override
    public void onDone(String imagePath) {
//You can use Glide or Picasso library to load this captured image to your preferred image view

    }
});
cameraViewDialog.setOnCaptureCancelledListener(new OnCaptureCancelled() {
    @Override
    public void OnCancelled() {

    }
});
cameraViewDialog.setOnRecapturingListener(new OnRecapturing() {
    @Override
    public void onRecapturing(int times) {

    }
});
cameraViewDialog.startDialog();
```

Comment: i need to upload 3 different image in to 3 different image view.

Comment: shud i use switch case in onactivityresult

Comment: You can use a switch or you can setOnClickListner for every one of them, with different camera dialogs and finally onDone the image will be inserted in the clicked imageView

Comment: can u share the code of setOnClickListner with different camera dialogs for atleast two imageviews

Comment: Put the same code I provided inside your listeners then use Glide to put the image inside your imageview in OnDone()